# Have any French weapons been spotted on the ground in Ukraine?

Tags: ukraine, france, weapons, foreign-aid

France has refused to publicly disclose what ["defensive military equipment"](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/france-provide-defensive-military-equipment-ukraine-army-spokesman-2022-02-26/) it's been sending to Ukraine, [in order](https://www.wsj.com/livecoverage/russia-ukraine-latest-news-2022-03-09/card/france-won-t-detail-military-support-to-ukraine-to-avoid-provoking-russia-V1csLhxaNQh4Ymoeyq7g) not to "provoke" Russia.

But there are plenty of country-specific weapon systems that would give away their origin, especially given the thousands of combat footage videos posted in the age of the smartphone. Everything from Panzerfausts to NLAWs to Javelins were sighted in such footage. But have any French weapons been seen?

Comment: Maybe they only sent International weapons to avoid this. Surely the French army won't only have French weapons.

Comment: @Trilarion: They don't seem to have a lot of those, e.g. 76 Javelins. Fewer than Estonia had (128) unless they bought more.

Comment: Surely there are more weapons than only Javelins in an army, even if you only count everything smaller than a small tank.

Comment: @Trilarion: in theory. The thing is the French army is almost exclusively equipped with French equipment. E.g. their only AA missile is the Mistral. Most of their ATGM are French too: Milan, MMP etc. Probably the only thing that's not so is the Swedish AT4, but the Swedes themselves have sent 5,000 or 10,000 of those to Ukraine (sources differ a bit).

Comment: could it be medical supplies or even supplies for logistic ?

Comment: Your first article is from Feburary 26th, a month old by now. Is that still the official French position on the matter?

Comment: @quarague: the 2nd one is from March 9. I haven't seen any newer sources on the issue.

Comment: I think le monde reported that France was sending 'dozens' of Milan to Ukraine at some point... but then Italy has sent Milan missiles too.

Comment: @CDJB: thanks; I found [the article](https://www.lemonde.fr/international/article/2022/03/09/la-france-livre-des-missiles-antichars-milan-a-l-ukraine_6116758_3210.html). It says "a few dozen". I guess that's why I haven't seen them in Ukrainian footage yet.

Comment: https://www.europe1.fr/international/guerre-en-ukraine-quelles-armes-sont-elles-livrees-par-la-france-4097971 . Lethal stuff seems being send under "defensive weapons". Furthermore France seems to have sent a lot of miscellanous stuff that doesn't shine like a big missile but will definitively by usefull on the long run (protective gear, medical supplies, mine finder,...). Also all this stuff is probably harder to identify from a photoshoot than an american rifle.

Comment: @Trilarion For the most part, yes, it does with only a few exceptions (e.g. equipment for the special forces, things France was late to develop like UAVs, cranes, bulldozers, and civilian vehicles). I know former Army officers who are sour that France does not produce assault rifles anymore and chose the HK416 as the standard weapon in the Army.

Comment: The Javelin purchase is interesting in that respect. It was one of several emergency purchase because the French Army found itself poorly equipped in Afghanistan. @Fizz They have already been retired while waiting for a [French missile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missile_Moyenne_Port%C3%A9e) to replace the MILAN.

Answer (score 5):

Yes - I commented a few weeks ago that [Le Monde had reported](https://www.lemonde.fr/international/article/2022/03/09/la-france-livre-des-missiles-antichars-milan-a-l-ukraine_6116758_3210.html) that, according to an unnamed diplomatic source, France had delivered 'a few dozen' MILAN anti-tank guided missiles to Ukraine - my translation below:

> Between 25 and 28 February, Paris, like other European capitals, provided protective equipment, helmets and bulletproof vests. But since then, according to our information, France has been delivering Milan anti-tank missiles to Ukrainian fighters. Taken from French army stocks, the quantity appears, for the time being, to have remained modest - "a few dozen", between 28 February and 3 March, according to a diplomatic source.

More recently, footage has emerged of Ukrainian troops being trained on the use of these missiles. A [report by CNN on the Mozart Group](https://edition.cnn.com/videos/world/2022/04/12/us-military-veterans-training-ukrainian-soldiers-lead-tapper-pkg-vpx.cnn), headed by retired US Marine Andy Milburn, which is providing support to the Ukrainian forces, contained a few brief clips of these systems on the ground in Ukraine - at 1:30 and 2:36 - screenshot from the first clip below with the 'MILAN' logo visible on the weapon case. As far as I'm aware, this report on April 12th is the first footage of French weapons on the ground in Ukraine.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Emmanuel Macron confirmed on April 22nd in [an interview with French newspaper *Ouest France*](https://www.ouest-france.fr/politique/emmanuel-macron/le-risque-d-escalade-en-ukraine-est-tres-fort-d79f638e-c1a5-11ec-8a48-02f9bba22954) that France had delivered weapons to Ukraine:

> Q: You say that Ukraine must be helped, also militarily. Should Europe provide heavy weapons, in particular tanks, like the German Leopard tanks? 
> A: Everyone takes their responsibilities with their political balances, and I do not interfere in the political life of others. We are very coordinated. The day before yesterday, I spoke to Chancellor Scholz about this subject. **We are delivering a lot of equipment, from Milans to Caesars and several types of weapons.** I think we should continue along this path. But we must always keep a red line, which is not to enter into cobelligerence.

The Caesar is an all-terrain truck equipped with a 155 mm cannon with a range of 40 km.
According to [another article](https://www.ouest-france.fr/europe/france/la-france-va-livrer-des-canons-de-155-mm-a-l-ukraine-d94045ea-c219-11ec-8207-1f0e356db714), 12 Caesar will be sent to Ukraine.